# Is it just my computer, or does the string `+[char]'ߡ'` with a -1 on the end mess things up?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was doing some Powershell coding, when I had to use this string:

```
`+[char]'ߡ'`
```

but I had to add a "-1" before the trailing backquote. But no matter what I tried in my text editor,

```
`+[char]'ߡ'-1`
```

would be the result. Does this happen to you as well??

1. Try typing:

   ```
   `+[char]'ߡ'`
   ```

   Into notepad++ or Chrome's Omnibox, etc.
2. Place the cursor 12 places into that string, (in between `'` and `` ` ``) and type  `-1`.

Does it come out correctly? Because it doesn't for me, and it doesn't on my other computer either.

Why does this happen? And does it happen on your computer? Or just mine?

#### TESTED ON WINDOWS 10 x32

Comment: The same thing happens if you type `-1` at the very end, after the backquote, as well.

Comment: Also it doesn't even need the backquotes. Even if you remove the backquotes from the beginning and end, it *still* does it.

Comment: What is the character code for that glyph? The behaviour looks a lot like what I'd expect to see after a right-to-left mark... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

Comment: @Mokubai `UTF-8/2017` is the number.

Comment: +1 on the rtl character idea, [](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B07e1) @Mokubai

Comment: `‏` is the rtl code, not ߡ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing the correct behavior. That triangle-looking character `ߡ` is [U+07E1 NKO LETTER MA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/07e1/index.htm). The [N'Ko script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%27Ko_alphabet) is right-to-left, so that character exhibits a strong preference for RTL rendering. The hyphen is "weak" when it comes to RTL, as are European digits, but European numbers [will become RTL](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#W2) if the first strong preference behind them is RTL. Once you type the `1`, the reordering happens and the hyphen comes along for the ride, since it's between the number and the N'Ko letter. Latin letters are strongly left-to-right, so those would not be affected.

Even though the text appears to get reshuffled, the character data doesn't change; the `-1` is really after the N'Ko letter and outside the single quote. Saving `+[char]'ߡ'-1` to a `.ps1` file and running it prints `2016` without a syntax error. Also, pasting that text into the PowerShell console doesn't produce RTL rendering; you just get a box instead of the N'Ko letter.